# Eclipse Juno Java EE IDE with Tomcat7 - ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat7, buildpath

I have a webapp installed and running but everytime I attempt to connect to the MySQL database using JDBC connection I get a CLASSnotFOUNDexception.

The mysql-java-connector jar is in my WEB-INF/classes as well as WEB-INF/lib folders. Its on Eclipse's Build path as well but somehow the jar is not being deployed. I've tried adding the jar separately to the build path as well. I've been stuck here for quite a well.

Can someone direct me on how to deploy the jar?

Heres part of the code I use to connect with my database.

```
public class JdbcConnection {
    public Connection connection;

    public JdbcConnection(){
        String serverLocation = "";
        String db = "";
        String user = "";
        String password = "";

        try{
            InputStream in = JdbcConnection.class.getResourceAsStream("/props/database.properties") ;
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.load(in);
            serverLocation = props.getProperty("serverLocation");
            db = props.getProperty("db");
            user = props.getProperty("user");
            password = props.getProperty("password");
            System.out.println(password + user + db + serverLocation);
           } 
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("error" + e);
           }     

        createConnection(serverLocation, db, user, password);
    }

    public JdbcConnection(String serverLocation, String db, String user, String password){
        createConnection(serverLocation, db, user, password);
    }
```

Here is the error that comes up in the console.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com/mysql/jdbc/Driver

Here is the create connection method

```
public void createConnection (String serverLocation, String db, String user, String password){
    //register driver
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    } catch (InstantiationException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    //              hostName = "jdbc:mysql://" + serverLocation+"/"+db+"?autoReconnect=true";
    String hostName = "jdbc:mysql://" + serverLocation+"/"+db+"?autoReconnect=true&useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8";
    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(hostName,user,password);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
```

Comment: Is your application a dynamic web application? And are you trying to start tomcat from eclipse (servers) or are you using eclipse just to generate the war?

Comment: I'm deploying a dynamic web applciation and starting tomcat from eclipse.

Comment: and can you see mysql-java-connector if you open Project > Java Resources > Libraries (in Eclipse)?

Comment: What class is the `ClassNotFoundException` happening on?

Comment: @JavaMentor Yes the jar is present at Project > Java Resources > Libraries > Web App Libraries.
Its happening on com/mysql/jdbc/Driver and the path exists in the .jar I checked.

Comment: could you paste the code you are using to perform the connection?

Comment: public JdbcConnection(String serverLocation, String db, String user, String password){
  createConnection(serverLocation, db, user, password);
 }

Comment: are you loading the driver? Please past the relevant code with the question ;)

Comment: I've posted the entire snippet of the code, I hope its the right parts. I'm not very proficient with Java.

Comment: @karthik Post the `createConnection()` method as well.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I posted it.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat 6.x and higher demands that you put all JDBC driver JARs in its /lib directory.

Remove it from WEB-INF/classes (it does no good there, anyway) and WEB-INF/lib, redeploy your WAR, and you'll be able to move onto your next error.

Believe me, you're still doing it wrong.  It will work if you do it properly.

I'd recommend doctoring this class and making a connection to MySQL without Eclipse or Tomcat.  If you can manage that, move up the ladder one step.

```
package persistence;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

/**
 * util.DatabaseUtils
 * User: Michael
 * Date: Aug 17, 2010
 * Time: 7:58:02 PM
 */
public class DatabaseUtils {
/*
    private static final String DEFAULT_DRIVER = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
    private static final String DEFAULT_URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:1521:database";
    private static final String DEFAULT_USERNAME = "username";
    private static final String DEFAULT_PASSWORD = "password";
*/
/*
    private static final String DEFAULT_DRIVER = "org.postgresql.Driver";
    private static final String DEFAULT_URL = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/party";
    private static final String DEFAULT_USERNAME = "pgsuper";
    private static final String DEFAULT_PASSWORD = "pgsuper";
*/
    private static final String DEFAULT_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private static final String DEFAULT_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/party";
    private static final String DEFAULT_USERNAME = "party";
    private static final String DEFAULT_PASSWORD = "party";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long begTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        String driver = ((args.length > 0) ? args[0] : DEFAULT_DRIVER);
        String url = ((args.length > 1) ? args[1] : DEFAULT_URL);
        String username = ((args.length > 2) ? args[2] : DEFAULT_USERNAME);
        String password = ((args.length > 3) ? args[3] : DEFAULT_PASSWORD);

        Connection connection = null;

        try {
            connection = createConnection(driver, url, username, password);
            DatabaseMetaData meta = connection.getMetaData();
            System.out.println(meta.getDatabaseProductName());
            System.out.println(meta.getDatabaseProductVersion());

            String sqlQuery = "SELECT PERSON_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME FROM PERSON ORDER BY LAST_NAME";
            System.out.println("before insert: " + query(connection, sqlQuery, Collections.EMPTY_LIST));

            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
            String sqlUpdate = "INSERT INTO PERSON(FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) VALUES(?,?)";
            List parameters = Arrays.asList("Foo", "Bar");
            int numRowsUpdated = update(connection, sqlUpdate, parameters);
            connection.commit();

            System.out.println("# rows inserted: " + numRowsUpdated);
            System.out.println("after insert: " + query(connection, sqlQuery, Collections.EMPTY_LIST));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            rollback(connection);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            close(connection);
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("wall time: " + (endTime - begTime) + " ms");
        }
    }

    public static Connection createConnection(String driver, String url, String username, String password) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Class.forName(driver);
        if ((username == null) || (password == null) || (username.trim().length() == 0) || (password.trim().length() == 0)) {
            return DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        } else {
            return DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        }
    }

    public static void close(Connection connection) {
        try {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public static void close(Statement st) {
        try {
            if (st != null) {
                st.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void close(ResultSet rs) {
        try {
            if (rs != null) {
                rs.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void rollback(Connection connection) {
        try {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.rollback();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static List<Map<String, Object>> map(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
        List<Map<String, Object>> results = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
        try {
            if (rs != null) {
                ResultSetMetaData meta = rs.getMetaData();
                int numColumns = meta.getColumnCount();
                while (rs.next()) {
                    Map<String, Object> row = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                    for (int i = 1; i <= numColumns; ++i) {
                        String name = meta.getColumnName(i);
                        Object value = rs.getObject(i);
                        row.put(name, value);
                    }
                    results.add(row);
                }
            }
        } finally {
            close(rs);
        }
        return results;
    }

    public static List<Map<String, Object>> query(Connection connection, String sql, List<Object> parameters) throws SQLException {
        List<Map<String, Object>> results = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

            int i = 0;
            for (Object parameter : parameters) {
                ps.setObject(++i, parameter);
            }
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            results = map(rs);
        } finally {
            close(rs);
            close(ps);
        }
        return results;
    }

    public static int update(Connection connection, String sql, List<Object> parameters) throws SQLException {
        int numRowsUpdated = 0;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        try {
            ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

            int i = 0;
            for (Object parameter : parameters) {
                ps.setObject(++i, parameter);
            }
            numRowsUpdated = ps.executeUpdate();
        } finally {
            close(ps);
        }
        return numRowsUpdated;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've included all .jar in my /Web-INF/lib/ as well as /WEB-INF/classes/ folder.

Comment: Please read the answer I gave you - both are utterly wrong.  Do as I suggested and see if that works better.

Comment: Nope. Not working. Just copied all my .jars into /libs of tomcat7. Still the same error persists.

Comment: Not all your JARs - just the MySQL JDBC JAR.  Read the answer.

Comment: That whole props thing is wrong-headed, too.  You really ought to learn how to create a JNDI data source.

Comment: Yes I did put the mysql-jdbc-connector-5.1.24-bin.jar in the lib folder. Still no luck. I restarted the server and still the same error.

Comment: is the `newInstance()` needed ?

Comment: @LittleChild No, but it doesn't affect the result.

Comment: I'd recommend seeing if you can create a connection at all, without Eclipse or Tomcat.  Can you write a simple class that connects to MySQL?  If not, why bother confusing yourself with Eclipse and Tomcat?